# Need help on wordpress pagination script

Tags: pagination

Could you please check what is wrong in pagination script. Actually I have set 4 post limit and there around 8 posts in my blog. When click on 2 pagination, it won't move to next page.

Please check with [link](http://equigreen.in/blog/) for live example

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => the_post(),
    'posts_per_page'         => '3',
    'paged' => $paged
);
?>

<?php

// The Query
$cquery = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $cquery->have_posts() ) : $cquery->the_post();
?>
<div class="row">
                        <div class="img"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="imgPos"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></a></div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" style="color:#545454;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <h3 style="line-height: 1px;"><span class="floatL">By &nbsp;</span> <span class="floatL"> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;</span> <span class="floatL">&nbsp; - &nbsp;</span> <span class="floatL"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></span><div class="clr"></div></h3>
                            <p><?php the_content('Read More') ?></p>

                        </div> 
                        </div> 
<?php
$post->ID;
endwhile;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
?>

<div class="row">
<div class="pagination">
<?php
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' =>  $cquery->max_num_pages
) );
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Why have you removed your code. I have properly edited it. Please, when you add code in the editor, highlight it and click on the `{}` sign. this will add your code in a code block

Comment: HoH thank you, i was wondering that i have no rights to add code.. lol

Comment: Can you please help me with above script

Comment: Thank you very much.
A guy VRajesh from Stackexchange have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

here you just need to change on $args array. where you have pas wrong argument.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'         => 3,
    'paged' => $paged
);
```